# Navegador notifica atividade no título mas não atualiza perguntas

Tags: bug, status-pronto

Recentemente notei algo estranho no stackoverflow em português.

Quando estou em outra página e tem uma atividade aparece no título "(1) Stack Overflow em Português" até ai normal.

Ai quando clico na tab, o conteúdo não está sendo atualizado. Só atualiza quando clico no logo ou se der F5. Antigamente isso não acontecia.

A nunca mudança que fiz recente foi adicionar algumas tags favoritas.

Uso google chrome.

Comment: Aqui também está com o mesmo problema. >> http://i.stack.imgur.com/Im3dG.jpg

Comment: Comigo também esta acontecendo isso, ele notifica mas não mostra a pergunta nova.

Comment: Aqui acontece o mesmo (Firefox 48.0.1, IE 11, Opera 39.0, Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, Firefox Dev 50.0a2).

Comment: Mesmo problema, notifica na aba mas não aparece a mensagem no topo das perguntas. (Frefox 47.0.1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a side-effect of some changes to improve accessibility; it should work as expected in a few minutes (I'm deploying currently).

(via google translate)

Este foi um efeito colateral de algumas mudanças para melhorar a acessibilidade ; ele deve funcionar como esperado em poucos minutos (eu estou implantando atualmente) .

Comment: Thank you for support! :)

Comment: Marc same effect on [Portuguese Language](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com), can you check this?

Comment: @JorgeB. I deployed a fix hours ago; could you refresh and let me know if there is still a problem?

Comment: Marc unfortunately we don't have many questions on PL. When I can test I give you feedback.

Comment: @JorgeB. for reference, the code is identical on all sites; I'm not going to say there *can't* be site-specific differences (there often are for bizarre reasons), but I would *expect* that if it is fixed anywhere, it is fixed everywhere

Comment: Ok I understand.

Comment: @MarcGravell is working ;)